# "Error while processing statement" running a query finding unique values with multiple values in other rows

Tags: oracle-sql-developer, jdbc, hive

Is there anything wrong in the syntax of this query finding unique values with multiple values in other rows?

```
Select Distinct Ss.`cd`, Ss.`cd`
From nit.assrr As Ss
    Join (
       Select `cd`
       From nit.assrr
       Group By `cd`
       Having Count(Distinct `cd`) > 1
      ) As Y
On Ss.`cd` = Y.`cd`
```

I am getting this error:

> [Cloudera]HiveJDBCDriver ERROR processing query/statement.
>
> Error Code: 2, SQL state: Error while processing statement: FAILED:
> Execution Error, return code 2 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask, Query:  .. my query

Comment: What is the DBMS? MySQL, Oracle or something else?

Comment: Besides the syntax issue, have you checked that the query will return 0 rows (always, no matter what data the table has)?

Comment: Are you using Hive? If yes, which version exactly?

Comment: What is the definition of `nit.assrr` (including keys)? As ypercubeᵀᴹ points out the current query do not work. Post `CREATE TABLE`statements and `INSERT`statements for sample data as well as expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you are using a Hive version that is before 0.13.0. In that case the problem is the `AS` keyword when giving alias to subquery.

From HiveQL documentation [Subqueries in the `FROM` Clause](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+SubQueries):

> ```
> SELECT ... FROM (subquery) name ...
> SELECT ... FROM (subquery) AS name ...   (Note: Only valid starting with Hive 0.13.0)
> ```
>
> ...
>   The optional keyword "AS" can be included before the subquery name in **Hive 0.13.0** and later versions (HIVE-6519).

Therefore, valid syntax would be:

```
Select Distinct Ss.`cd`, Ss.`cd`
From nit.assrr AS Ss
    Join (
       Select `cd`
       From nit.assrr
       Group By `cd`
       Having Count(Distinct `cd`) > 1
      ) Y                                  -- AS removed
On Ss.`cd` = Y.`cd` ;
```

---

Regarding the semantics of the query. I'm not sure what the actual problem is but this query is guaranteed to return 0 rows, no matter what the data in the table are.

`COUNT(DISTINCT cd)` will be 1 when you have `GROUP BY cd` so the `HAVING` clause will be `FALSE` always and the `Y` subquery will have 0 rows.